# jquery validate form with ajax call to external php file that checks all fields and block form submit if there is error message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I want to validate form field on submit event. I am sending ajax request to php file that checks the fields and returns error message or nothing if all is OK. Here is the js code I have:

```
$('form.p_form').submit(function (){
var description = $.trim($('#f9').val());
//this blocks form submit if empty field and it works
if(description === '') return false;
//this doesnt work
if(description !== ''){
var aa = $.post("checkdescription.php",{
     description: description
 },
 function(data, status){
    if(data !== ''){
    return data;
    }
 });

 //here I need to know the response text returned from ajax so I can say like this:
 if(aa === 'error message'){
 return false;
    }
 }
});
```

Please help, I am stacked and I am posting this question for second time as I could not get help, Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `aa` will not contain any data that you are expecting (in fact it may contain the promise returned from calling the `post` method of AJAX).

*Moreover you're using the default synchronous type of ajax call with the `post` method*.

In order to have access to the returned data (even outside of the promise) you may use `$.ajax` with the property `async: false` as such:

```
 var aa = ''; //the result
 $.ajax({
     url: "checkdescription.php",
     async: false,
     data: {
     description: description
     }, 
     success: function(data, status){
         aa = data;
      }
});
```

Then, you can check the value of the variable `aa` soon after the ajax call.

```
 if(aa === 'error message'){
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: you will need a `}` after `aa = data;` or the code will break.

Comment: Ahmad it looks like your code does the job ! Thank you all guys for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compare the response synchronously with an asynchronous get call. The value of `var aa` won't be set by the callback function until after the ajax call has completed. You have to keep that in mind when trying to compare synchronous vs asynchronous.

So let's go step-by-step what would happen with your code here:

1. Form submit
2. [Presumption] description isn't blank
3. `var aa` = undefined
4. Ajax post is called to `checkdescription.php`
5. `aa` does not equal "error message"

`aa` will never equal `'error message'` and hits the end of your submit function (because the value of `aa` still hasn't been set yet by the completed ajax response

6. (This will probably never in this code, but let's pretend it could) The ajax call returns a response and then your call back function would be instantiated and it would either return data or false. Now `var aa` has a value.

Answer (score 0):

Script should catch response in 'data' variable of post request. i.e. either empty on success or 'error message' on error. Please try below and check if this works for you.

```
var aa = $.post("checkdescription.php",{
 description: description
 },
 function(data, status){
  // data will be empty is everything is ok and "error message" if there is validation error
   if(data == 'error message'){
       // handle error
   } else {
      // on success it should be here
   }
 });
```

Comment: Yogesh I am getting error SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
 

}); with your code